# Find number of occurrences in a map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to create a map in C++ and I will use it to compare wheater a vector of string match another one. The condition is that only one word can be taken into consideration. For example, given:

```
{"two", "times", "three", "is", "not", "four"}
{"two", "times", "two", "is", "four"}
```

In this case they shouldn't match because there is only one `"two"` in the first vector.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void checkMagazine(vector<string> magazineWords, vector<string> noteWords)
{
    map<string, int> magazine;
    map<string, int>::iterator it = magazine.begin();

    //populating the map
    for (string magazineWordString : magazineWords)
    {
        it = magazine.find(magazineWordString);

        if (it != magazine.end())
        {
            int numberOfOccurences = it->second;
            magazine.insert(pair<string, int>(magazineWordString, numberOfOccurences + 1));
        }
        else
        {
            magazine.insert(pair<string, int>(magazineWordString, 1));
        }
    }

    //checking for correspondences
    for (string noteWordString : noteWords)
    {
        it = magazine.find(noteWordString);

        if (it != magazine.end())
        {
            int numOfOccurences = it->second;
            magazine.insert(pair<string, int>(noteWordString, numOfOccurences - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "There is no match." << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    cout << "There is a match!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your criteria for a "match?" Namely, can you give more examples of good and bad matches?

Comment: @scohe001 the vector `magazineWords` must have all the elements of `noteWords` to match

Comment: So if in your example, you're showing that `magazineWords` must have all of the elements of `noteWords` and those elements must appear at least as many times as they do in `noteWords`. Is that correct?

Comment: If a key is already present, inserting a new pair with the same key will not change the map. Instead, use the iterator to access the pair and increment its count.

Comment: @scohe001 correct, so if `noteWords = {"two", "times", "two", "is", "four"}`, then `magazineWords` MUST have two `twos` to match.

Comment: If noteWords has all of the words of magazineWords with the proper count and some extra words does it match? If magazineWords has two occurrences of "two" and noteWords has three occurrences does it match?

Comment: @RetiredNinja it does not. `magazineWords` must have the same or more occurrences of an element in `noteWords`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a far easier way! The subscript operator on a map will try to find the key in the map. If it is successful, it returns a reference to its value. Otherwise, it creates a new key/value pair for you on the spot and gives you a reference to *its* value.

So since the default value of an `int` will be 0 (that is, when we create a new key/value pair, the value will be 0), all your work can actually just be:

```
bool checkMagazine(vector<string> magazineWords, vector<string> noteWords)
{
    map<string, int> bank;

    //populating the map
    for (string magazineWord : magazineWords) {
        ++bank[magazineWord];
    }

    //checking for correspondences
    for (string noteWord : noteWords) {
        if(--bank[noteWord] < 0) { return false; }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Watch it run here: https://ideone.com/MzLAJM